# Reshape Array Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

lets say I have an array of the form

```
Y=
 array([[[6.45285536, 4.13302386]],

   [[7.6683039 , 7.66590237]],

   [[6.65061296, 5.79469154]],

   ...,

   [[7.43964513, 4.18676161]],

   [[4.95229954, 7.41067346]],

   [[4.02962837, 6.64919938]]]
```

and the shape looks like

```
Y.shape
   (1000, 1, 2)
```

how can I convert/reshape this such that it has

```
(1000,2)
```

?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html

Comment: `Y.reshape(-1, 2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reshape your `numpy` array as `Y.reshape(-1,2)`

Comment: thank you, this worked well! 
is there an easy way to add a new column to a given array? 
I mean like going from (100,2) ---> (100,3)?

Comment: thanks. I would appreciate if you can create a new question so that others can benefits also.

Comment: I can post a question once per 90min.. I will post it as soon as possible